# IE specific CSS not being used in IE?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have some trouble defining CSS for only IE. This is the IE specific code in my header:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../default/css/ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
```

...

I am running IE11 and I think the first if should be used which means, ie.css should be loaded. I changed all the used CSS files, just to make sure. Changes I make there are not reflected. I am changing the correct CSS file.

Do I have to do anything else here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionals are no longer supported:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Your solution will work for legacy versions of the legacy browser but not 11.